# TypeError: Input has ['int', 'str'] as feature name / column name types

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit a ML model and I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: Feature names are only supported if all input features have string names, but your input has ['int', 'str'] as feature name / column name types. If you want feature names to be stored and validated, you must convert them all to strings, by using X.columns = X.columns.astype(str) for example. Otherwise you can remove feature / column names from your input data, or convert them all to a non-string data type.`

My code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import csv
import warnings
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression, Perceptron
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Reading the data
train_url = 'https://github.com/Rakesh9100/ML-Project-Drug-Review-Dataset/raw/main/datasets/drugsComTrain_raw.tsv'
test_url = 'https://github.com/Rakesh9100/ML-Project-Drug-Review-Dataset/raw/main/datasets/drugsComTest_raw.tsv'

dtypes = { 'Unnamed: 0': 'int32', 'drugName': 'category', 'condition': 'category', 'review': 'category', 'rating': 'float16', 'date': 'string', 'usefulCount': 'int16' }
train_df = pd.read_csv(train_url, sep='\t', quoting=2, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=['date'])

train_df = train_df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=42)
test_df = pd.read_csv(test_url, sep='\t', quoting=2, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=['date'])

## Extracting day, month, and year into separate columns
for df in [train_df, test_df]:
    df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day.astype('int8')
    df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month.astype('int8')
    df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year.astype('int16')

## Suppressing MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning, FutureWarning and ConvergenceWarning
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)

## Defining function to decode HTML-encoded characters
def decode_html(text):
    decoded_text = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').get_text()
    return decoded_text

## Applying the function to the review column
train_df['review'], test_df['review'] = train_df['review'].apply(decode_html), test_df['review'].apply(decode_html)

## Dropped the original date column and removed the useless column
train_df, test_df = [df.drop('date', axis=1).drop(df.columns[0], axis=1) for df in (train_df, test_df)]

## Handling the missing values
train_imp, test_imp = [pd.DataFrame(SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent').fit_transform(df)) for df in (train_df, test_df)]

## Assigning old column names
train_imp.columns = ['drugName', 'condition', 'review', 'rating', 'usefulCount', 'day', 'month', 'year']
test_imp.columns = ['drugName', 'condition', 'review', 'rating', 'usefulCount', 'day', 'month', 'year']

## Converting the text in the review column to numerical data
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=3000)
train_reviews = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_imp['review'])
test_reviews = vectorizer.transform(test_imp['review'])

## Replacing the review column with the numerical data
train_imp.drop('review', axis=1, inplace=True)
test_imp.drop('review', axis=1, inplace=True)
train_imp = pd.concat([train_imp, pd.DataFrame(train_reviews.toarray())], axis=1)
test_imp = pd.concat([test_imp, pd.DataFrame(test_reviews.toarray())], axis=1)

## Encoding the categorical columns
for i in ["drugName", "condition"]:
    train_imp[i] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(train_imp[i])
    test_imp[i] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(test_imp[i])

## Converting the data types of columns to reduce the memory usage
train_imp, test_imp = train_imp.astype('float16'), test_imp.astype('float16')
train_imp[['drugName', 'condition', 'usefulCount', 'year']] = train_imp[['drugName', 'condition', 'usefulCount', 'year']].astype('int16')
test_imp[['drugName', 'condition', 'usefulCount', 'year']] = test_imp[['drugName', 'condition', 'usefulCount', 'year']].astype('int16')
train_imp[['rating']] = train_imp[['rating']].astype('float16')
test_imp[['rating']] = test_imp[['rating']].astype('float16')
train_imp[['day', 'month']] = train_imp[['day', 'month']].astype('int8')
test_imp[['day', 'month']] = test_imp[['day', 'month']].astype('int8')

#print(train_imp.iloc[:,:15].dtypes)
#print(test_imp.iloc[:,:15].dtypes)

## Splitting the train and test datasets into feature variables
X_train, Y_train = train_imp.drop('rating', axis=1), train_imp['rating']
X_test, Y_test = test_imp.drop('rating', axis=1), test_imp['rating']

##### LinearRegression regression algorithm #####

linear=LinearRegression()
linear.fit(X_train, Y_train)
line_train=linear.predict(X_train)
line_test=linear.predict(X_test)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e787292883ec> in <cell line: 89>()
     87 
     88 linear=LinearRegression()
---> 89 linear.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     90 line_train=linear.predict(X_train)
     91 line_test=linear.predict(X_test)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _get_feature_names(X)
   1901     # mixed type of string and non-string is not supported
   1902     if len(types) > 1 and "str" in types:
-> 1903         raise TypeError(
   1904             "Feature names are only supported if all input features have string names, "
   1905             f"but your input has {types} as feature name / column name types. "

TypeError: Feature names are only supported if all input features have string names, but your input has ['int', 'str'] as feature name / column name types. If you want feature names to be stored and validated, you must convert them all to strings, by using X.columns = X.columns.astype(str) for example. Otherwise you can remove feature / column names from your input data, or convert them all to a non-string data type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a prefix to your `TfidfVectorizer` output to convert your columns of integer to strings:

```
train_imp = pd.concat([train_imp, pd.DataFrame(train_reviews.toarray()).add_prefix('review')], axis=1)
test_imp = pd.concat([test_imp, pd.DataFrame(test_reviews.toarray()).add_prefix('review')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> train_imp
        drugName  condition  rating  usefulCount  day  month  year  review0  ...  review2992  review2993  review2994  review2995  review2996  review2997  review2998  review2999
0           2276        816    10.0           24   26     11  2016      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
1            852        252    10.0           31   25      7  2009      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
2           1633        297     8.0           31   21     12  2011      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
3           3224        443     7.0           17   20      1  2013      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
4            915         87    10.0           20   11      4  2015      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
...          ...        ...     ...          ...  ...    ...   ...      ...  ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
129033      2668        157     9.0            4    4      7  2016      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
129034      1665        157     1.0            9    6      1  2017      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
129035      1089        157     9.0            8    8     10  2016      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
129036       157        387    10.0           13    9      2  2015      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
129037      1112        157     1.0            1   14      9  2017      0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0

[129038 rows x 3007 columns]
```

Tips:

Replace:

```
## Handling the missing values
train_imp, test_imp = [pd.DataFrame(SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent').fit_transform(df)) for df in (train_df, test_df)]

## Assigning old column names
train_imp.columns = ['drugName', 'condition', 'review', 'rating', 'usefulCount', 'day', 'month', 'year']
test_imp.columns = ['drugName', 'condition', 'review', 'rating', 'usefulCount', 'day', 'month', 'year']
```

With:

```
## Handling the missing values and assigning old column names
train_imp, test_imp = [pd.DataFrame(SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent').fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns) for df in (train_df, test_df)]
```

Comment: can I know what it means to add 'review'?

Comment: The problem is that you create a dataframe without column names so Pandas uses `RangeIndex` to create names from 0 to N, so the column dtype is int. Since you use `review` column to create your matrix, I added `review` name as prefix of the `RangeIndex` so now the column dtype is str. Now your columns are review0, review1, review2, etc...